# Migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL and sychronize it

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, database-migration

I want to migrate from mysql to postgresql to improve my data's control but I found several problems:

1. I have two applications that can only be run over mysql and a new
   aplication that I want to migrate to postgresql.
2. I need to redesign several parts of the old database (mysql) and
   apply the new design in the new database (postgresql).
3. If I insert a new row in some tables of old database, this row
   should be synchronized to the new database with the new design

For doing this, I've been thinking to use a data wrapper, and synchronize data using triggers( I only need to synchronize data in one way (mysql to postgresql)).

Do you think that's a good choise to solve this problem?
Any ideas/advise?